# Aframe mobile can't detect orientation of the device

Tags: iphone, mobile, aframe

I'm working on a project with A-Frame. My problem is that when I open from my iPhone (model Xs Max) even the easiest example code moving the device will not change the camera rotation. But when i go to https://aframe.glitch.me/ this one works even if it is the same code. The device motion and orientation is enabled in iPhone settings. What am I missing?

Comment: Make sure you are serving your app over https. Share a link to an example that doesn't work if the problem persists.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if torre is a est ti bypass thai and make it work even in http?

Comment: No. Safari and Chrome mobile enforce `https` for devicemotion. No workarounds possible.